# AssertionError when using MirroredStrategy: isinstance(x, dataset_ops.DatasetV2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, assertion

I am trying to use **MirroredStrategy** to fit my sequential model using two Titan Xp GPUs. I am using `tensorflow 2.0` alpha on ubuntu 16.04.

I successfully run the code snippet from the tensorflow documentation:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf

mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
  with mirrored_strategy.scope():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))])
  model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(([1.], [1.])).repeat(100).batch(10)
model.fit(dataset, epochs=2)
model.evaluate(dataset)
```

However, when I try to train on my data, which is a sparse matrix of shape (using adam optimizer and binary crossentropy):

```
Shape X_train: (91422, 65545)
Shape y_train: (91422, 1)
```

I receive an assertion error in _distribution_standardize_user_data at

```
assert isinstance(x, dataset_ops.DatasetV2)
```

In the `TensorFlow` code, line 2166 in [training.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py) seems to be causing this assertion error.

Can someone explain to me what the problem with my data could be?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error when using `dataset= strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(train_dataset)` with `model.fit(dataset)` .

I after I remove the `strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset`. It works fine. It is similar to the [TF document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) where they said that `keras.Model.fit()` handle everything automatically and we need distributed dataset manually only when we want to do customized training with `tf.GradientTape()`.

You can go through the [offical tutorial of MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training) for more info

Answer (score -5):

Seems like you are feed dataset into model.fit, model.fit are expecting an numpy.ndarray.